# Twilio Remove listeners from conversations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, twilio, twilio-conversations

Hello trying to make a conversations app based on twilio

The app is doing fine but everytime someone clicks a Conversation from the Conversations List, it starts a useEffect, the useEffect has something like the following function:

```
  const setChannelEvents = useCallback((channel) => {
    channel.on('messageAdded', (message) => {
      setMessages(prevMessages => [...message, prevMessages])
    })
```

**The problem** is that every time we leave the conversation that listener stays ***on*** so every time someone clicks on a conversation the app is creating a loot of listeners and well that isn't cool.

Wondering how to turn off the listener when it leaves the component

Tried something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Twilio.getClient()
      .then((client) => client.getConversationBySid(channelId))
      .then((channel) => setChannelEvents(channel))
      .catch((err) => console.log('err', err.message))
      .finally(() => setLoading(''))
    
      return () => chatClientChannel.current.removeListener('messageAdded')
  }, [channelId, setChannelEvents])
```

Didnt work

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think your `useEffect` is mostly right, but you are potentially using a different object in the return clause to the original channel. The beauty of a React hook like `useEffect` is that you can encapsulate some of the state in the function, and then use that in the tear down.

Try this instead:

```js
  const handleMessageAdded = (message) => {
    // do something with the new message
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let currentChannel;
    Twilio.getClient()
      .then((client) => client.getConversationBySid(channelId))
      .then((channel) => {
        currentChannel = channel;
        return setChannelEvents(channel);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('err', err.message))
      .finally(() => setLoading(''))
    
      return () => { 
        if (currentChannel) {
          currentChannel.removeListener('messageAdded', handleMessageAdded);
        }
      };
  }, [channelId, setChannelEvents]);
```

Here you set the `currentChannel` (I'm using `let` to define the variable and then updating it once the promise resolves. You could also do this by breaking your promise chain up into `await`ed functions that set the `currentChannel`) in the `useEffect` function, then remove the listener from that same object in the tear down function.

Comment: This almost works we had to make the listener a function and the remove like this `.removeListener(eventName, handler)` Thanks!

Comment: Ah, good point. I've updated my answer to reflect this too.